# Combining JQuery Validation followed by ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, post

I'm sure this is simple but I'm new to JQuery.  I am using the JQuery plugin to validate an email address, this works and the code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#email").click(function () {
        $(this).attr({value: ''});
    });
    $("#subscribe-form").validate();
});
```

What I then want to do is to post the email address using an ajax post, again this code works fine without the validator:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var data = "email=" + email;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "subscript.php",
            data: data,
        });
    });
});
```

What I don't seem to be able to do is combine them both, so that if the email is valid it will then post.  I'd really appreciate help on how to do this.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`.validate()` can be configured by passing in an object with various configuration options. In this case, setting the [`submitHandler`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) with a callback to your form submission code should do the job.

I've also cleaned up your example code a bit, in an effort to show you how to write more idiomatic jQuery.

1. I've used [`jQuery.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) instead of [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) since `jQuery.ajax()` is a low-level method which is only used when you want to customize the behaviour of an AJAX request, much like how we're customizing the behaviour of `.validate()`.
2. All inputs of the form can be prepared for posting by invoking [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/). This prepares a [URL encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding) key-value string like `name=John+Doe&email=john%40doe.com`, which can then serve as data for a POST.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/H8pHv/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myForm').validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.post('subscript.php', $('#myForm').serialize());
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You ought to be able to use the [`submitHandler`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) option, which would essentially be a callback function which is invoked when the form is validated:

```
$('#submit').click(function () {
    $("#subscribe-form").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            //do submit
        }
    });
});
```

> Callback for handling the actual submit when the form is valid. Gets
>   the form as the only argument. Replaces the default submit. The right
>   place to submit a form via Ajax after it validated.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like the following before your ajax call to invoke validation:

```
    if (!$('form').valid()) {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before making the `.ajax()` call, check if the form is valid before proceeding using `if ($('#subscribe-form').valid()) { ... }`.