# HTML 5 native validation is not working in JQuery UI model box but Jquery validation using plugin is working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, validation

I am using a JQuery model box where HTML 5 native validation is not working.

My code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/inDiscover/btnwZ/)

Also I am adding the code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery UI Dialog: Open Dialog </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
//$('#pop_up_form').validate();    
$("#popup").dialog({ 
autoOpen: true,
title : "View/Edit Screen",             
dialogClass : "pop-content pop-header-colr pop-button pop-float",
width:400,
height:450,
modal: true,
resizable: false,
show: 'clip',
buttons:{
'SUBMIT':function(){
/*if($('#pop_up_form').valid())
{
alert("successfull");
}*/
}   
}

});

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="popup" style="display:none">
<form action="" name="pop_up_form" id="pop_up_form" method="post"><input class="pop_up_textbox" type="text" name="acct_nmbr" id="acct_nmbr" required maxlength="19" value=""/></form>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here if you are un-commenting those jquery code that I commented , you can see that the Jquery validation is working fine. But why HTML5 validation is not working here if I am commenting the Jquery validation code. To test HTML 5 validation I have added an attribute "required" for a form field , but some how this is not working.

I know that for HTML 5 doctype should be `!DOCTYPE HTML`. I have added this also but no luck. Is it because of UI dialog box which doesnt support HTML 5 native validation.

Comment: It's not working because of your jQuery.  See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/btnwZ/2/),  I've added a submit button in your HTML and it works with that button.

Comment: Which one are you wanting to do? HTML5 Validation or jQuery Validation plugin? You cannot do both. The HTML5 Validation is automatically disabled when you use the jQuery Validation plugin.

Comment: Actually I am using modernizr to detect the HTML 5 features and depend on that I need to trigger either Jquery validation or HTML 5 native validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually happening because your modal box's button doesn't trigger HTML5 validation.

You cannot use use both HTML5 and jQuery validations.  If you want to go with just HTML5 validation while still using jQuery,  you can do something like this for your `submit()` in your situation to let it call HTML5 validation.

```
function(){
    $('#pop_up_form .submit').click();
    return false;
}
```

For this to work,  you will need to have a hidden input in your form HTML

```
<input type="submit" class="submit" style="display:none;"></input>
```

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/btnwZ/4/)

I still see people using browsers that don't support HTML5,  you may want to re-think this.

Comment: Thanks... I can see the native validation here. But one question , I have already written a submit function by using an option "button" and this is also same as a form submit event right?? . As you mentioned If I am writing a submit event again , it is a kind of submitting the form twice. Right??. My knowledge in Jquery is very less so Please help me clarify on this.

Comment: Your form will not be submitted twice,  instead your jQuery submit will simulate the click of HTML button.  Your jQuery button is doing nothing except asking the hidden HTML submit to do what it normally does.

Comment: Thanks alot....This info is much helpful... But I am wondering why it(" jQuery submit will simulate the click of HTML button. Your jQuery button is doing nothing except asking the hidden HTML submit to do what it normally does") has not documented in Jqueri UI Dialog API documentation.

Comment: These are not official jQuery standards they document, they just tell you about the basic functionality.  They can't cover all possible situations in their documentation.  You will learn tricks like these to manipulate your HTML DOM elements along the way of your learning. jQuery is very versatile and it will let you do much more than you can probably think right now.

Comment: One more thing... I have modified the code here http://jsfiddle.net/btnwZ/5/  But this is not working. My intention is I need to write some thing inside the function after HTML 5 validation is successfull. How to do this.

Comment: Do you mean you want to call ajax? What do you want to do after clicking submit.  The data will be submitted.  You need to be clear about your problem.  This is not mentioned in your question,  this is a completely different issue than what the title or question speaks.

Comment: Your callback function was written wrong. it take the syntax `.on('click', function(){//...do stuff..});`.  and why do you want to select `$(document)`?  it will call the function when you click anywhere on the complete document.  The corrected code to your fiddle will be http://jsfiddle.net/btnwZ/6/

Comment: Yes I need to make an ajax call inside, if the HTML 5 validation is successfull. I can do the ajax call but I need to call only after the validation is successfull.I dont know how to do this. I was thinking about to post another question but later on I thought it would be better to post here itself.Sorry for making this question as unanswered.I will make it answered but please help me resolve this as I am in tight situation as tomorrow I need to move this to QA.

Comment: The fiddle  sfiddle.net/btnwZ/5 that I have provided contain id of a particular element in the document so it will check for that id and the function will get triggered.And what you meant by corrected code in the fiddle jsfiddle.net/btnwZ/6 that you had provided ,bcz I couldnt see any change.

Comment: I would recommend using jQuery `.validate()` is such a case.  it will make your life easy.  Trying to force HTML5 validation and then using AJAX to submit is going to be very messy(though it's possible). You can start [from here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7915827/1369473).  Covering this in this post is out of scope because it will initiate a different level of discussion.  I honestly recommend you to post a new question for this if you are still unable to figure out a way.

Comment: I Opened a separate question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427837/checking-html-5-validation-is-successful-or-not

Answer (score 0):

It is working, but you aren't seeing anything because there is no default styling (*in some browsers like Chrome version 35.0.1916.153 on Mac*) for errors. Just add some CSS and it'd be good to go, I've added a bit of CSS to your code so you can see what I mean: [HTML5 Validation](http://jsfiddle.net/btnwZ/1/)

**CSS**

```
input:required:invalid, input:focus:invalid {
  background:red;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: But why we need to add css it is an HTML 5 native validation. Right??When I am displaying the same form without using any dialog box then its showing an error mesage without adding any css. Can you please help me understand why I need to add css in case of dialog box.

Comment: It is validating, but you won't see anything in some browsers like Chrome (at least not until version 35.0.1916.153 Mac) because it doesn't include default styling for invalid elements.

I've tested your code in Firefox 30.0 (Mac) and it sets the input border to red when failing. My answer lets you "see" when an input validation failed, nothing else.

Comment: I agreed it may be validating. I tested this code in google chrome (34.0.1847.131 m) without using dialog box also I didnt add any css but its working fine , I mean I got chrome's HTML 5 validation message. In the same version of browser I tested the code by using dialog box but I am not able to see the validation message. As you said if we cannot see anything in some browsers then my question is why I cannot see the HTML 5 native validation message in Jquery UI dialog box.This should not happend right.I also agreed that you are showing me that validation is happening but why this discrepency.

Comment: Because HTML5 Form validation is still a work in progress, vendors make the best they can to follow the specification but there are still issues. Here you can see browsers support for Form Validation: http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation check the "Known Issues" tab. Every browser will handle this in a different way, even same browsers for different operative systems. At least it'll be like this until the final specification for HTML5 form validation has been published.