# Checking HTML 5 validation is successful or not

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I need to check whether HTML 5 native validation is successful or not. Based on this I need to call an ajax function.

An example code is here. http://jsfiddle.net/inDiscover/4Pbcp/

Also providing the example code as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery UI Dialog: Open Dialog on Clicksssssssssss</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery-ui.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $("#pop_submit").click(function() 
                {
                    alert("am here");
                    //return false;
                });

            });
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="popup" style="display:block">
            <form action="" name="pop_up_form" id="pop_up_form" method="post">
                <input class="pop_up_textbox" type="text" name="acct_nmbr" id="acct_nmbr" required maxlength="19" value=""/>
                <input type="submit" name="pop_submit" id="pop_submit" style="display:block;" />
            </form>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Here in the jquery code I have put an alert while submitting the button. But I need to show this alert only after successful HTML 5 native validation. If any one can point me out that is how can I achieve this then I can call an ajax function instead of an alert message after successful HTML 5 native validation.

I know we can use JQuery Validator to validate a form by using valid() method but I don't wanna go in that way. I need to know whether my HTML 5 native validation is successful and if it is I need to do some logic.

Comment: can any one answer this question. If no such technical persons are there to answer this question I think I should close this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The checkValidity() method (part of the HTML5 validation API) should do what you need.  This tutorial is very helpful in explaining the native HTML5 form validation methods: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/.

Comment: You have to do the `checkValidity` in the form's `submit`event or it won't show the native client's notification. Here is how to keep your click event if you need it for other elements: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53922759/301753